# Creating filter in WebApi2 to filter Images

Tags: c#, filter, asp.net-web-api2

I a newbie to webapi and have created a web api project. Different controller method here needs image as parameter. I am using an external 3rd party api to check if the image uploaded by the users is not any profane image. So instead of checking it at actionMethod level ,i thought it might be a good idea to check using a filter that way it will save me time of checking it individually. But i haven't got a clue as to how to start writing the code for this.

```
 public class ImageFilter : FilterAttribute,IFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext httpActionContex)
    {
        if(!httpActionContex.ActionDescriptor.) // ???? what should come
    }
}
```

please guide me. Don't need the exact code just the correct direction and guidance .. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A FilterAttribute is, as its name implies, an attribute that can be set globally on the WebAPI pipeline, or individually on a specific controller method. You can simply slap the `[ImageFilter]` attribute on your specific controller method, and the WebAPI pipeline will execute the filter before executing the action method - giving you a chance to filter what requests make it to the method.

For the actual implementation of your custom logic, you can access the `HttpContext.Current.Request` in your `OnActionExecuting` method, allowing you to access the incoming HTTP request. You can then read the data from it, pass it to your 3rd party API, and if it doesn't pass the filter, you can access the Response and end it before it even reaches the controller:

```
    var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest; // or whatever
    response.End();
```